# Android SDK preference in eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I have recently updated my android adt to adt 20. But i am now facing a problem.It is saying that  location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preference. I have updated and installed many plugin in the android sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

**Window -> Preference -> Android -> SDK Location**

Set the path of the Android SDK in your computer there.

Comment: can you tell me when i have updated my android to adt-20 ,where my adt-20 zip file stored bt default?

Comment: It would get updated in the location where the previous versions were there. The zip file is automatically unzipped by eclipse and the installation is made at the same location where the existing versions were there.

Comment: And don't forget to upvote the answer if it was of any help. Thanks! =)